# jQuery fade in new wrapper after old one faded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `#wrapper` with three elements.  I `fadeIn`/`slideToggle` them all then fade out the whole screen.  Then, once the `#wrapper/whole` screen has faded out I'm trying to `fadeIn` a new picture.

For, some reason the last `fadeIn` of `#baby-grand` isn't working.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#paul-bedal").hide();

    $("#is-amidst").hide();

    $("#Paul-picture").hide();

    $("#baby-grand").hide();

    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#paul-bedal").fadeIn(3000, function() {
            $("#is-amidst").slideDown(4000, function() {
                $("#Paul-picture").fadeIn(3500, function() {
                    $("#wrapper").fadeOut(5000, function() {
                        $("#baby-grand").fadeIn(3500);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
    min-width:960px;
    max-width:1200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#wrapper {
    min-width:960px;
    max-width:1200px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#paul-bedal {
    height:150px;
    width:650px;
    margin-top:150px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    font-size:95px;
    color:#E3E3E3;
    text-shadow:5px 5px 5px #f6f6f6;
}

#is-amidst {
    height:100px;
    width:650px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    font-size:55px;
    color:#E3E3E3;
    font-style:italic;
    text-shadow:5px 5px 5px #f6f6f6;
}

#Paul-picture {
    background-image:url(/images/Paul-Bedal.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:250px;
    height:500px;
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
    margin-right:50px;
    margin-top:-100px;
}

#baby-grand {
    background-image:url(/images/baby-grand-piano.png);
    width:100%;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}


<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="Paul-picture"></div>

    <div id="paul-bedal">
        Paul Bedal
    </div>

    <div id="is-amidst">
        ~is amidst right now...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="baby-grand"></div>
```

Also, note that `#baby-grand` is not wrapped inside `#wrapper`, so it's a pretty simple maintenance page. But, the last `#baby-grand` fade in isn't working in jQuery.

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe I just did that.  Thanks man

Comment: It's actually still not working.  It's a PNG now.  All the code is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that  is empty and doesn't have any height. It infact fades In but there is nothing to display! try to give it some height via css to see if it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your background on the #baby-grand is a psd. Browser can't display it.